# Modify data before validation step with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple `Model` that stores the user that created it with a `ForeignKey`. The model has a corresponding `ModelSerializer` and `ModelViewSet`.

The problem is that when the user submits a `POST` to create a new record, the `user` should be set by the backend. I tried overriding `perform_create` on the `ModelViewSet` to set the user, but it actually still fails during the validation step (which makes sense). It comes back saying the `user` field is required.

I'm thinking about overriding the `user` field on the `ModelSerializer` to be optional, but I feel like there's probably a cleaner and more efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: in models make user field as blank=True

Comment: Right, but that seems slightly hacky since it really always does need to have a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the `user` field as [`read_only.`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

This will ensure that the field is used when serializing a representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance during deserialization.

In your serializers, you can do something like:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user' : {'read_only' : True} # define the 'user' field as 'read-only'
        }
```

You can then override the `perform_create()` and set the `user` as per your requirements.

Comment: Quick and clean, just how I like it :)

Answer (score 36):

I came across this answer while looking for a way to update values before the control goes to the validator.

This might be useful for someone else - here's how I finally did it (DRF 3) without rewriting the whole validator.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data['user'] = '<Set Value Here>'

        return super(MyModelSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

For those who're curious, I used this to round decimal values to precision defined in the model so that the validator doesn't throw errors.

Comment: According to me, this is a good practice as we are able to separate the business logic from the views. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: using this is giving me expception
```AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

Comment: @Madhusudanchowdary you can set the `data._mutable` as `True`. Found it on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717442/this-querydict-instance-is-immutable

Answer (score 2):

Old topic but it could be useful for someone.

If you want to alter your data before validation of serializer:

```
serializer.initial_data["your_key"] = "your data"
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I feel that this logic should be placed in the serialiser or model.